# Panorama Control, Tap

Tags: windows-phone-7, tap, panorama-control

I'd the UI design for Windows Phone using Panorama Control, but the "Tap" is not functioning in my code. Wondering why? My XAML code as follow:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
<StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,0">
<HyperlinkButton Tap="detailmap_Tap" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Style="{StaticResource EmptyButtonStyle}">
            <Image Name="titleImg" Width="480" Height="150" />
</HyperlinkButton>
        <toolkit:PerformanceProgressBar Name="prgBar01" Margin="0,0,0,0" Visibility="Visible" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsEnabled="True" IsIndeterminate="True" />
        <TextBlock Name="locationNote" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,0,0,0" />
    </StackPanel>
<controls:Panorama Title=" ">
        <!--Panorama item one-->
        <controls:PanoramaItem Header="test1">
            <Grid/>
</controls:PanoramaItem>

<!--Panorama item two-->
        <controls:PanoramaItem Header="test2">
            <Grid/>
</controls:PanoramaItem>
</controls:Panorama>
</Grid>
```

This UI design work perfectly, except the "Tap" in the hyperlinkButton doesn't respond. Any ideas?

Comment: Based on your xaml, your Panorama is on top of your hyperlink button. Is this xaml correct? Also Hyperlink has a Click event which would be better suited

Comment: I do suspect the reason not working is because the Panorama control is "on-top" of the "stackpanel", but I don't know how to revert it.

Comment: Answer is simple, revert the position of the two control, and it work perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

If you want a button to be visible no matter which Panorama item the user is on, place the Panorama below the button

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto">
        <RowDefinition Height="*">
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <HyperlinkButton Grid.Row="0"/>
    <controls:Panorama>
        <controls:PanoramaItem />
    </controls:Panorama>
</Grid>
```